# Use multiple Pageable parameters in Spring MVC endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a situation like this

```
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository repo;

@RequestMapping("/")
public Page<Customer> getDocuments(@Qualifier("bar") Pageable pageable,
                                   @Qualifier("foo")Pageable pageable2)
{
    return repo.findAll(pageable,pageable2.getOffset(), pageable2.getPageSize());
}
```

but it did not work well. My question is, how can I distinguish between the parameter values.

To achieve the above scenario I had to change my method to this:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public Page<Customer> getDocuments(Pageable pageable,
                                   @RequestParam(value="from", defaultValue="0") int offSet,
                                   @RequestParam(value="length", defaultValue="3") int length)
{
    return repo.findAll(pageable, offSet, length);
}
```

Comment: People here, not Einstyne at least mention the reason in comments before downvoting @WoEver-Downvoted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I have found my answer. What I did was absolutely correct but I was passing the wrong parameters in my URL.

In short, if you are passing two Pageable there has to be a @Qualifier and you need to set your request parameter accordingly.

what I was passing before in URL `http://localhost:8080/?page=0&size=2&page=0&size=3`
and the correct URL would be `http://localhost:8080/?bar_page=0&bar_size=2&foo_page=0&foo_size=3`

PS: whoever downvoted my question I am still mad at him/them.

Comment: i tried the same url but it is not hitting my rest method.

Comment: That solution works perfectly fine and it easy to implement. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think it is wrong idea to pass Spring beans as argument to rest resource. If the values needs to be accessed from Bean, then it should access inside the resource assuming bean is already initialized.

`@Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repo;

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("bar")
Pageable pageable;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("foo")
Pageable pageable2;

@RequestMapping("/")
 public Page<Customer> getDocuments(){

   return     repo.findAll(pageable,pageable2.getOffset(),pageable2.getPageSize());
}`
```

Comment: by saying Pageable I mean to say this http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html. which I am passing to the Method It has nothing to do with Autowiring.

Comment: at class definition use generics which extends Pageable interface. like class MyController <R extends Pageable>. Then at Rest method use R instead of Pageable, like @RequestBody R pageable1

Comment: tried it says the same java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous Pageable arguments in handler method. If you use multiple parameters of type Pageable you need to qualify them with @Qualifier

Comment: Did you add @Qualifier?

Comment: I did before but I think that was wrong because all I need to pass 2 page size arguments and 2 offset arguments. Typically when you pass one Pageable with the method parameter it works perfectly.

Comment: You can't send 2 RequestBody object. Instead use Map as RequestBody and send those 2 Pageable as part of Map. This might reduce the burden of RequestBody

Comment: I have solved the problem look at my answer. And thanks for the support, because no problem can be solved alone.